# Lua: ANSI escapes pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm writing logging library for Lua, which actually is something like rewrite & bundle of some npm modules (like log-update, chalk, etc.). I want to get true width of string, so I need to strip ANSI escape codes from it. I found npm module that provides [regexp for it](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/blob/master/index.js). But I don't understand how to match these characters in Lua via Lua patterns. Can you help me to write pattern, which does it?

Comment: Have a look at [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/UcvM6N/2) you found: it is not possible to convert it as a single Lua pattern since it contains alternation, quantified groups. Well, limiting quantifiers can be "emulated" using `%d%d?%d?%d?` for `\d{1,4}`. It might be possible to split it into separate patterns that you will have to run one after another. Well, I cannot figure out how to convert `(?:[a-zA-Z\d]*(?:;[a-zA-Z\d]*)*)?` to Lua patterns.

Comment: `text = string.gsub(text, "[\27\155][][()#;?%d]*[A-PRZcf-ntqry=><~]", "")`

Comment: What are the escape sequences terminated with bell character?  Do they really exist?

Comment: I don't really understand what is 'bell character'. But thanks for pattern.

Comment: Bell character is `\u0007`

Comment: Bell character is itself escape sequence, no? Try to execute `sleep 3 && lua -e "print(string.char(7))"` in terminal and go to another workspace.

Comment: Can you create an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
text = string.gsub(text, "[\27\155][][()#;?%d]*[A-PRZcf-ntqry=><~]", "")
```

Thanks to [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff)!